# Changing amount of rows/columns raster via Model Builder in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

Because I want to convert a raster to ASCII file to use it in PMWIN I have to change the amount of rows and columns of several rasters.

I now do it with Raster Calculator and then specify the new layer, but since it is necessary for many maps and with different rows/columns (some parts need to be more refined than others) it would be nice if there is a function in the model builder that let's me specify the Xmin/max, Ymin/max, amount of rows and amount of columns.